# GitHub Codespaces subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, apartment-gem, codespaces

I run the Ruby on Rails application on the [GitHub Codespaces](https://github.com/features/codespaces).

It works fine when I am not logged in.

But when I log in, it will be redirected to the subdomain by [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment#switch-on-subdomain) GEM.

And get an error message `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

Is there any way to solve this problem? thanks.

[image: Your connection is not private]

Comment: Hi Amo, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @zevstatiev no 